# If $m(Z)=0,W=\{x^2: x\in Z\}$, how to prove that $m(W)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is my question,

If $m(Z)=0, W=\{x^2: x\in Z\}$, how to prove that $m(W)=0$? Here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I have no idea about it, can anyone give me a hint or answer?

Comment: Note $f (x) = x^2$ is locally Lipschitz and that the enumerable union of sets with measure zero has measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $g : x \mapsto x^2$. We have to prove that $m(g(Z)) = 0$. We have $W = \cup_n W_n$ where $W_n = W \cap [n,n+1)$ where $n \in \mathbb N$.

It is enough to prove that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $m(W_n) = 0$. And this is the case as $W_n = g([\sqrt n, \sqrt{n+1})) \cup g([-\sqrt{n+1}, - \sqrt n))$ and $g$ is absolutely continuous on $[\sqrt n, \sqrt{n+1}), [-\sqrt{n+1}, - \sqrt n)$ as it is Lipschitz continuous on those bounded intervals.

Comment: I got it, thanks a lot!